# Is there any example of Kalman Filter with OpenCV in Java?

Tags: opencv, kalman-filter

I am using OpenCV 3.0 beta, I want to use Kalman Filter, but I cannot find any example of the Kalman Filter implementation in Java OpenCV. I have tried the example code in C++ and Python, but I cannot completely translate this code to Java.

Comment: Apache Commons Math has a Kalman Filter https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/filter/KalmanFilter.html

Comment: Dear Downvoter, though it appears request for example, using Kalman Filter in Java was not easy till OpenCV 3.0 and even now docs doesn't help much on it. Try porting the KalmanFilter C++ example to Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing you might miss when porting OpenCV C++/Python Kalman filter sample to Java is how to set transition/control or measurement matrices. Unfortunately Opencv java doc([1](http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/video/KalmanFilter.html)) for Kalman filter doesn't mention those methods. Hope this code sample([2](https://github.com/Franciscodesign/Moving-Target-Tracking-with-OpenCV/blob/e1ceb8b716984d105de7d375a70ba7a937f27a82/src/sonkd/Kalman.java)) from github helps. You *might* need OpenCV 3.0 though.

```
KalmanFilter kalman = new KalmanFilter(4, 2, 0, CvType.CV_32F);
Mat transitionMatrix = new Mat(4, 4, CvType.CV_32F, new Scalar(0));
float[] tM = { 1, 0, 1, 0, 
        0, 1, 0, 1,
        0, 0, 1, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 1 } ;
transitionMatrix.put(0,0,tM);
kalman.set_transitionMatrix(transitionMatrix);
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend taking a look at the Efficient Java Matrix Library ([ejml](http://ejml.org/)). They provide several Kalman filter implementations in the [examples](https://github.com/lessthanoptimal/ejml/tree/master/examples/src/org/ejml/example) (see the `KalmanFilterSimple` class for a concrete example).